# Formulating an alternating sum of product combinations

Tags: combinatorics, summation, products, inclusion-exclusion

Consider some list $A=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$. I'd like to find a closed form for the following operation.

$$f(A)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}s_k= s_1-s_2+\cdots(-1)^{n-1}s_n.$$
Where $s_k$ is the sum of all combinations of products of $k$ unique elements of $A$. For example, if $A=(x,y,z)$, then
$$s_1=x+y+z,$$
$$s_2=xy+xz+yz,$$
$$s_3=xyz.$$
Thus $f(A)=(x+y+z)-(xy+xz+yz)+(xyz)$.

> What is the "nicest" way to formulate this sum of products?
>
> Is this operation known/common in combinatorics?

The best I can come up with is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\prod_{a\in\mathcal{P}_n(A)}a$$
where $\mathcal{P}_n(A)$ denotes the set of all subsets in $A$ with cardinality $n$. However, it would be nice to have this in some "standard form" without the use of powersets (let alone the generalization of such). My binomial theorem alarm is going off; thus I imagine there is some nicer closed form which makes use of binomial coefficients.

Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By checking some test values, it appears to equal $1-\prod_{k=1}^n(1-a_k)$ at least for the cases I've checked for $n=3$; although the proof is not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: This form reminds me of the so-called Inclusion–exclusion principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: @VezenBU Wow! Seems we have found a duality indeed. This came up while studying fuzzy logic, so there is certainly a connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you got is correct. We directly use the binomial expansion to get
\begin{align}
\prod_{k =1}^n (1-a_k) 
&= \sum_{j = 0}^n \sum_{C \in \binom{[n]}{j}} \prod_{c \in C} -a_c \\
&= \sum_{j = 0}^n \sum_{C \in \binom{[n]}{j}} (-1)^{j} \prod_{c \in C} a_c \\
&= 1 + \sum_{j = 1}^n \sum_{C \in \binom{[n]}{j}} (-1)^{j} \prod_{c \in C} a_c \\
&= 1 + \sum_{j = 1}^n (-1)^{j} \sum_{C \in \binom{[n]}{j}}  \prod_{c \in C} a_c \\
&= 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^n (-1)^{j - 1} \sum_{C \in \binom{[n]}{j}}  \prod_{c \in C} a_c \\
&= 1 - \sum_{j = 1}^n (-1)^{j - 1} s_j
\end{align}